# Path from list of path parts with pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib, toml

I want to generate a path based on a list inside the configuration toml. I have chosen a list to be able to support different operating systems.

For example the following list is stored inside my configuration.toml:

```ini
temporary_storage_folder = ["~", "temp", "machine_name"]
```

This should then be converted into a Path object.

The trivial constructor seems not to exists, so:

```py
from pathlib import Path
Path(["~", "temp", "mesomics"])
```

does not work.

I came up with the following solution

```py
from pathlib import Path
config_list = ["~", "temp", "machine_name"] # is actually parsed from the toml
path_list = [Path(x) for x in config_list]
path_obj = Path(*path_list)
```

but I'm not sure if this is best practice or the pythonic way of achieving my goal. I'm also open to suggestions on how to otherwise save a general path in a config.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```py
from pathlib import Path
config_list = ["~", "temp", "machine_name"] 
storage_obj = Path(*config_list)
```

Which generates:

```
PosixPath('~/temp/machine_name')
```

In terms of specific usage for config files, I would use Pydantic with a Path field:

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings
import pathlib

class SetupConfig(BaseSettings):
    path_obj: pathlib.Path
```

Then you can add your own validators to ensure the path is valid (such as, if it actually exists and the path is a directory and the directory has the correct stuff within it)

Comment: so what does the unzip generate? Not a tuple of strings? Because you can't do something like `test = *config_list'

Comment: The path object takes in a list of string (or string like). This unpacks the list as separate arguments into the Path object

Comment: So, you would generate a pydantic "Validator" class for the whole config. And when parsing the toml, you would add a call to the pydantic "Validator" constructor, which then validates the whole config and ensures that everything is set correctly?

Comment: The pydantic validator can be set on individual fields and you can have a validator for the whole config together. https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/